# Unable to get ASP.NET MVC and Web API routing straight in my mind - getting 404s galore

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am struggling with routing issues in my ASP.NET MVC + WebAPI app. I feel like I have a moving target here because when I add or change one route I break another.  Here is my specific example.

First, my controllers, so you can see the names:

[image]

Next, my MVC routing config (I understand that my config is probably duplicative, but it is because I am trying things):

[image]

And my Web API routing config (I understand that my config is probably very duplicative, but it is because I am trying things):

[image]

As a routing problem example, here's the PodcastFeeds API controller:

[image]

So I post to the Create action method...

[image]

And as you can see I get the error: `404 not found - "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`.

I would love some direction here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order or registering routes is important since requests are handled by the firs route that matches the patter. Because your default route is the first one it always selected. **You need to put your default route to be the last one and register all your routes starting from the most constraining and ending with default one.** Also Is I see in your screenshots some of your routes are not fully configured: for example `api/PodcastFeeds` route doesn't specify a controller (it needs to look similar to your `FeedRouteMap` route from the second screenshot):

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "PodcastFeeds",
  url: "api/PodcastFeeds/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new {controller="PodcastFeeds", action="Create", id=UrlParameter.Optional})
```

As an alternative you can use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) to avoid those kind of issues.

Comment: can you share your Global.asax content I need to see the Application_Start method

Comment: Here you go: `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();, FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);, WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);, RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` Note that I placed a breakpoint inside WebApiConfig.cs' `Register(...)` method and it was indeed hit.

Comment: I am confused between how MVC routing and Web API routing interact so as a result I'm unclear where to make the changes. Should I make the default route change in the routeconfig or in the webapi routing config? About your comment re: some of my routes not specifying a controller, I've edited that mapping to be: `Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:"PodcastFeedsAPI", routeTemplate:"api/PodcastFeeds/{action}", defaults:new { ApiController = "PodcastFeeds", action="Create" });` but I am getting same error. (Note that url didn't work for me and I had to do routeTemplate. Maybe because I'm Web API 2?)

Comment: I just found that replacing `api/PodcastFeeds/{Action}` with `api/{Controller}/{Action}` worked.  Why wouldn't putting the actual controller name in the route template work?  Also, you commented earlier that some of my routes were not fully configured since I hadn't specified a default controller.  But if I am directly specifying the controller name and action name in the url, eg "http://host/api/PodcastFeeds/Create", why wouldn't the mappings work without a default specified?

Comment: because you can create a route like this one: `Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:"PodcastFeedsAPI", routeTemplate:"api/MyController/MyAction", defaults:new { ApiController = "PodcastFeeds", action="Create" });` as you can see the controller name is different from the one you have in the route

Comment: I had assumed that a literal match of the url to the route template string and in turn a match to the controller name and action method name would by default map properly but I guess not.  Also, why don't the mappings work when you don't specify defaults?  I thought the purpose of defaults was, for example, in the case that, again for example, the controller was not specified in the request url.  If it is specified, why would a default be required?